# Getting records that failed to sync during Azure Data Factory "Copy Data" step

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cognitive-search

Is it possible, in some way, to get rows or any info about rows which were failed during Azure Data Factory Copy Data action executing and pass it to the next action in pipe?

Currently I sync data from Azure Sql Database into Azure Search Index. I picked up "Skip and log incompatible rows" as Fault tolerance action. 
In documentation I've found the next info:

> In addition, you can log the incompatible rows in Azure Blob storage
>   or Azure Data Lake Store. You can then examine the log to learn the
>   cause for the failure, fix the data on the data source, and retry the
>   copy activity.

But I'd really love to have some non manual way of resync for failed rows. Is there any way to do so out of the box (without creating any custom actions which get log file from storage, parse it and resync)? I have feeling that Fault tolerance option "Add dynamic content" might do the thing, but its functionality isn't really rich and is limited by using few functions and runtime variables.

Answer (score 1):

The fault tolerance doesn't support automatic way of resync.

If you want to do that, I think you can connect any activity after your copy acitivty which will be triggered on copy finished. Then the fault store will contain the bad data, you can run any activity against it.

The fault data csv format is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance#monitor-skipped-rows

> data1, data2, data3, "UserErrorInvalidDataValue", "Column 'Prop_2' contains an invalid value 'data3'. Cannot convert 'data3' to type 'DateTime'."
>   data4, data5, data6, "2627", "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tblintstrdatetimewithpk'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tblintstrdatetimewithpk'. The duplicate key value is (data4)."

Comment: Thanks for data format, it'll be handy. 
Yeah, I know I can do that manually, but as I mentioned before I'm in search of "any way to do so out of the box (without creating any custom actions which get log file from storage)"

Comment: As I mentioned,  "any way to do so out of the box (without creating any custom actions which get log file from storage)" is not supported. I guess this is the only way.